# OpenCV matchTemplate throws memory fault but only first time

Tags: c++, opencv

I am processing a set of >3000 images of same size changing template every 300 images.

code snippet:

```
cv::Mat inTplate, cFrame, Cresult;
Cresult.create(resultH, resultW, IPL_DEPTH_32F);
cFrame(rect).copyTo(inTplate);
...
// this part executed for every frame
matchTemplate(cFrame, inTplate, Cresult, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED); 
minMaxLoc(Cresult, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());
```

rect = ( 250, 20, 1420, 1040); and resultH = 41; resultW = 501;

the very first time thru the code, the call to matchTemplate throws a memory fault that i believe comes from combase.dll and references an address that is not in the space for any of the three matrices:  cFrame, inTplate or Cresult.

Also the sizes for the three matrices are consistent:  cFrame 1080 rows X 1920 cols, inTplate 1040 rows X 1420 cols; Cresult is 41 rows X 501 cols.  yes the first time inTplate is a region of cFrame; thereafter cFrame is the next image read in.

i verified that the answsers coming back from matchTemplate are correct -- the matching is correct. And the memory fault occurs ONLY on the very first call, not on any of the subsequent frames.

Am I doing something wrong or am i looking at a bug in OpenCV ?

thanks for taking the time.

Comment: i forgot to add that the answers coming back from matchTemplate are correct -- the matching is correct.  And the memory fault occurs ONLY on the very first call, not on any of the subsequent frames.

Comment: You can edit you own question.

Comment: I had a problem with memory faults being thrown, and in my case it was because the input Mats (`cFrame`, `inTplate` and `Cresult` in your case) all need to be floating point Mats.

Answer (score 0):

A sort of answer:

I modified my call to matchTemplate to use a try ... catch block.  but it wouldnt catch the exception.

Then I went into Debug | Windows | Exception Settings and turned *off* the checkbox for cv::Exception.

Now the program runs without stopping with a memory exception.  It would seem that i have now enabled OpenCV to catch the exception and deal with it.  So the underlying issue still exists but OpenCV is taking care of it.  i would still like to understand why the exception is being thrown in the first place, though.